# What technique can I use to store data

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, linq, database-design

I have an application where I am storing about 1kbyte of data every 0.1 second. That's 36MByte/hour, or roughly 600MByte/day.

The data is highly compressible, so it should compress between 10:1 and 100:1. All the data is referenced by timestamp.

My question is this: what technique can I use to store this data?

Constraints:

- The time to insert the data into the database cannot increase as the database size gets larger. This constraint rules out Microsoft SQL Server (we tried it, and after 5 days it ground to a halt as each "insert" was taking a minute).
- We can effectively pause the data recording for 4 hours per day, which would give us time to do compression, etc.
- We would like to compatible with LINQ for .NET, which means that we would probably need a database that a LINQ adapter (a MySQL style interface would be ok).

Comment: You had your SQL server configured incorrectly. It's possible to set it up so that an insert takes constant time indefinitely.

Comment: Inserts longer than a minute? 99% of the time, this is a problem with the query, not the database. Try specifying Insert with NOLOCK, and make sure that if you have indexes on your rows being inserted, the inserted row goes somewhere at or near the "end" of the index, rather than randomly in the middle.

Comment: I would re-evaluate the need to use Linq...  While I think Linq is awesome and I use it myself, for something like this, I would be wary of programming methods that encourage client-side processing (rather than server-side processing).

Comment: You didn't mention any requirement on the query side.  I would expect you need to do some kinds of query after you store the data.  If you need to do a query on the data you stored, storing the data in a plain file is not a choice for you then

Comment: @Juliet and @Greg Hewgill - thanks for the tips, perhaps we can use Microsoft SQL after all.

Comment: So, is this data structured or un-structured? Any examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to simply append your incoming data to a file on disk. After a day, switch to a new file, and then spawn a process to compress and store the previous day's file.

You seem to assume that you need to store your data in a database, without stating a reason why. Do you?

Comment: I'd like to have the data in a database so I can query it easily. LINQ queries are very expressive and make things a lot easier.

Comment: If you don't need today's data available immediately, then you could have the background process also do the actual inserting into the database. That way, your online logging isn't dependent on a database at all. This would be one aspect of a more robust system.

Comment: If there are no concurrent writers, this is actually a really nice solution that will scale very well.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't get SQL Server to handle that small of a load in a timely fashion, then I wonder if any RDBMS will be effective for you if you don't explore how you are inserting the data.

Are you doing just a very simple insert into a single table (with a primary key) that has no other indexes/functions/process blocking/reads ?  Or is this process actually a little more involved than this  simple/small insert you are talking about?

If you are dead set on using  Linq, are you profiling your linq statements to make sure you are not telling the ORM to do something stupid?

Comment: We're doing a simple insert. I'll do as you suggested - profile our LINQ to make sure we're not doing anything silly (like using "Orderby" which forces a load of the entire table into memory so it can be sorted).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can store all the contents onto a binary file and the meta data to the DB.